# SQL postgres extract week

Tags: sql, postgresql, extract

Could you help me to modify the following code to extract Distinct user_id per week and not per month please? A user_id could appear only 1 time during a given week.

```
 SELECT
COUNT(DISTINCT user_id),
 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created_at) Y,
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at) M
FROM user_logins
WHERE created_at >= '2017-01-01'
 AND created_at <= '2018-04-10' 
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created_at),EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at)
ORDER BY Y,M
```

OR

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id),
  to_char(created_at, 'YYYY-MM') YM
FROM user_logins
WHERE created_at >= '2017-01-01'
  AND created_at <= '2018-04-10' 
GROUP BY to_char(created_at, 'YYYY-MM')
ORDER BY YM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `WW` to extract the week number or the more standard [ISO week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering) using `IW` for this. You have to include the year with that as there are weeks in the "current" year that are partially in the last year or the next year.  When using `IW` you also need to use the "ISO year" that corresponds to that week number

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id),
       to_char(created_at, 'IYYYY-IW') as week
FROM user_logins
WHERE created_at >= '2017-01-01'
  AND created_at <= '2018-04-10' 
GROUP BY to_char(created_at, 'IYYYY-IW')
ORDER BY week;
```

This can also be done using the `extract()` function:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id),
       extract(isoyear from created_at) as year, 
       extract(week from created_at) as week
FROM user_logins
WHERE created_at >= '2017-01-01'
  AND created_at <= '2018-04-10' 
GROUP BY extract(isoyear from created_at), extract(week from created_at) 
ORDER BY week;
```

Comment: @ahorswithnoname  Thank you so much . Could you confirm that the following code do the job (one user per week) ?     SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ul.user_id), up.app_vendor_id, to_char(created_at, 'IYYYY-IW') as week
FROM quoine_mainuser_logins ul
JOIN (SELECT u.app_vendor_id, u.id FROM quoine_mainusers u WHERE u.app_vendor_id = 3) up
ON  ul.user_id = up.id
WHERE ul.created_at >= '2017-01-01'
  AND ul.created_at <= '2018-04-10' 
  GROUP BY to_char(created_at, 'IYYYY-IW'), up.app_vendor_id
ORDER BY week

Comment: @ahorswithnoname i checked on a given week. It seems it does not gives the right numbers. the same user_id appears several times in the same week.

Answer (score 0):

extract will give you the week number of the year, so if you have several years, the count will be for all years - so it's not per week, but rather "for any year week number":

```
t=# with c(d) as (values('2016-04-19'::date),('2017-04-19'))
select count(*), extract(week from d) from c group by extract(week from d);
 count | date_part
-------+-----------
     2 |        16
(1 row)
```

if you want data per week, as per unique time identifier, use `date_trunc` instead:

```
t=# with c(d) as (values('2016-04-19'::date),('2017-04-19'))
select count(*), date_trunc('week', d) from c group by date_trunc('week', d);
 count |       date_trunc
-------+------------------------
     1 | 2017-04-17 00:00:00+00
     1 | 2016-04-18 00:00:00+00
(2 rows)
```